# Can I limit what a user can see in a PowerPivot table/chart (e.g. slicer shows their department[s] only) using their AD credentials?

Tags: user-accounts, powerpivot

I want to produce a number of PowerPoint tables and charts and make them available to my entire management team but limit it so that the Department slicer only shows the department(s) that they manage. Can this be done in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is based on PowerPivot only then there is no way to apply row-based security.

However, you can take the Tabular database that is automatically created when the Excel file with PowerPivot is uploaded to SharePoint and modify that to introduce more granular security.